# ALign xml text using XSLT in ouput html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i have my XML like this

```
   <catalog>
       <cd>
          <p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt; font-size:5">Washington</p>
       </cd>
    </catalog>
```

and use the XSLT to get the and set the "washington" text align property

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="p">
      <p style="text-align:{substring-before(substring-after(@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';')}">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </p>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it works fine and give me required output `<p style="text-align: center">Washington</p>`
which align the text to center

but if i change the line to

```
 <p align="{substring-before(substring-after(@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';')}">
```

to get this `<p align="center">Washington</p>` 
then its not working to set the text to the center
where m going wrong

Comment: Above code produces `<p align=" center">Washington</p>`. So, what is the problem?

Comment: ya it produces this statement but its not aligning the text to the centre when rendered on using on browser which is exactly what i required.. :(

Comment: So it is question in HTML area.

Comment: i checked it again in different browsers and its working in Gcrome only not even in FF and IE
what to do to work in these browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may because of the space before the word "center" in your align attribute.

```
<p align=" center">Washington<p>
```

You need to use the **normalize-space** command to remove this extra space:

```
<p align="{normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';'))}">
```

This would output the following

```
<p align="center">Washington<p>
```